# Why is the ID for a subnet created using Azure Resource Manager Powershell cmdlets null?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-resource-manager, azure-virtual-network

I am trying to provision some network resources in Azure and I am running into a blocker with a step that tries to reference a previously created subnet's `Id` property.

Here's the command to retrieve the subnet details:

`$gwsubnet = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name 'GatewaySubnet' -VirtualNetwork $vnet`

And then outputting the value of `$gwsubnet` in the console:

`Name                 : GatewaySubnet
Id                   : 
Etag                 : 
ProvisioningState    : 
AddressPrefix        : 10.1.1.0/24
IpConfigurations     : null
NetworkSecurityGroup : null
RouteTable           : null`

Note that the `Id` property is null.  This causes an error for a future step, e.g.:

`$gwipconfig = New-AzureRmVirtualNetworkGatewayIpConfig -Name config1 -SubnetId $gwsubnet.Id -PublicIpAddressId $gwpip.Id`

Gives the following error:

`New-AzureRmVirtualNetworkGatewayIpConfig : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'SubnetId'. The argument is null or empty. Supply an argument that is not null or empty and then try the 
command again.
At line:1 char:99
+ ... nfig -SubnetId $gwsubnet.Id -PublicIpAddressId $gwpip.Id
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [New-AzureRmVirtualNetworkGatewayIpConfig], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Network.NewAzureVirtualNetworkGatewayIpConfigCommand`

I'm struggling with how to have my subnet have an `Id` assigned to it.  Is this something that I need to logout/login again to see?  thanks for the help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem you are having is that the subnet Id isn't created until you have created the virtual network.

When you run `Get-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig` all you create is a configuration to attach to `New-AzureRmVirtualNetwork` Once you have run that command it will connect to Azure, deploy the Vnet, create the subnet and at that state it will create a subnet Id.

The following code will show you what I mean...

```
$DNSNameLabel = "mydnsname"
$NetworkName = "MyNet"
$NICName = "MyNIC"
$PublicIPAddressName = "MyPIP"
$SubnetName = "MySubnet"
$SubnetAddressPrefix = "10.0.0.0/24"
$VnetAddressPrefix = "10.0.0.0/16"

$SingleSubnet = New-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig `
                -Name $SubnetName `
                -AddressPrefix $SubnetAddressPrefix

#At this point nothing is created, so there is no valid subnet id

$Vnet = New-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -Name $NetworkName `
                -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
                -Location $LocationName `
                -AddressPrefix $VnetAddressPrefix `
                -Subnet $SingleSubnet

#vnet and subnet are created, both get an id and etag

 $vnet = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -Name $NetworkName 
                -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName 

$vnet.Subnets[0].Id
```

Which will give

> /subscriptions/{Subscription ID}/resourceGroups/MyResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/MyNet/subnets/MySubnet